# How to disable a Value

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have an issue.

I have a page with Ads and I want to create a category and make all users except me to have access to it. I have found what i think can help me (just to disable the category from the category list of users) and I got that code now

```html
<select>
  <option class="level-0" value="42" selected="selected">Text1</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="15">Text2</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="40">Text3</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="18">Text4</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="43">Text5</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="36">Text6</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="17">Text7</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="41">Text8</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="19">Text9</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="16">Text10</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="38">Text11</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="39">Text12</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="1584">Text13</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="20">Text14</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="37">Text15</option>
</select>
```

and want to disable the Text13 line. The value for it is "1584" and I don't know how to hide or dissable it from the list. thanx

Comment: Add the attribute `disabled="disabled"` to that `option` tag.

Comment: You'd need some kind of scripting language to change the output for some but not all users.

Comment: AngularJS, or ReactJS are the ones you should look at to do that dynamically/depending on the user who is connected on the page. Changing the DOM elements, updating them and sending value to the view dynamycally will need you one of these frameworks in order to do something smooth, cool, clean, and that will not take you 3 years to hard code in JS.

Comment: How to do a [simple search](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_disabled.asp) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, the disabled  option will be grayed out

```html
<select>
  <option class="level-0" value="42" selected="selected">Text1</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="15">Text2</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="40">Text3</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="18">Text4</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="43">Text5</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="36">Text6</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="17">Text7</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="41">Text8</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="19">Text9</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="16">Text10</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="38">Text11</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="39">Text12</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="1584" disabled="disabled">Text13</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="20">Text14</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="37">Text15</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<select>
  <option class="level-0" value="42" selected="selected">Text1</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="15">Text2</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="40">Text3</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="18">Text4</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="43">Text5</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="36">Text6</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="17">Text7</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="41">Text8</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="19">Text9</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="16">Text10</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="38">Text11</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="39">Text12</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="1584" disabled >Text13</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="20">Text14</option>
  <option class="level-0" value="37">Text15</option>
</select>
```

can use also hide that line with

```
 <option class="level-0" value="1584" disabled style="display:none">Text13</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! (It's on a Wordpress site and I can't edit the HTML - sorry I didn't mention that before)

```
option[value="1584"] {display: none;}
```

Comment: You should do it in JS then, because this could lead to really funny behavior in the futur. _Why is this option disable ... there is no class, so this should be OK_ but you will find after 2days that this is an option is a different `select` with the value `1584`

Comment: If it's CSS only, then it will affect all users, surely? AxelH is right, you should at least target the select by `name` or `ID` in the CSS selector. i.e. `select[name=ad_category_eg] option[value="1584"]`. It's still not particularly robust but better than nothing.

Comment: I can't add or edit HTML cause of wordpress and this is an automatic fields that are adding whenever I add new category.